# scp remote to remote through local bandwidth limit

Tags: bandwidth, scp

I have two remote hosts, I need to transfer files from one to another. They don't have routing between each other, so I have to transfer it through local machine, that routes to both.

I can use `scp -i /path/to/key -3 remote1:/path/to/file remote2:/path/to/file` and everything works fine, except it uses all available bandwidth. Scp has option `-l` that limits bandwidth, but it works only when I transfer from remote to local or from local to remote. It doesn't work with option `-3`. I don't know if it is bug or desired behaviour, man page doesn't specify anything about it.

Any ideas how to make it easy and smooth with bandwidth limit control? Rsync is not available.

Comment: First start an ssh connection to the intermediate host and establish an SSH port forwarding to the destination host on that connection. Afterwards you can simply use scp on the forwarded port in "regular mode" so that `-l` should work again.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh remote1 "cat /path/file" | pv --rate-limit 1M | ssh remote2 "cat > /path/file"
```

Similar methods can be used to transfer multiple files at once:

```
ssh remote1 "cd /path && tar -cz file1 file2" | pv -L 1M | ssh remote2 "cd /path && tar -xz"
```